# Clicking on objects using the HTML5 Canvas and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a `mousedown` event listener that runs the following function:

```
function getPos(event) {
    var x = event.x;
    var y = event.y;

    x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
    y = canvas.offsetTop;

    for(var checker of board.checkers) {
        if(x >= checker.x + 32 && x <= checker.x - 32) {
            if(y >= checker.y + 32 && y <= checker.y -32) {
                alert("HE CLICKED");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since the checkers are circles, their origins are in the center, that is why I check checker.x + 32 or checker.x - 32.

For some reason the `alert("He clicked")` does not appear. When I was messing with the inequality symbols, I would get `alert("he clicked")`, but in the wrong situations.

Could someone shine some light on this problem please?

Comment: **Here's how to hit-test the mouse [x,y] versus a circle:** `if( (x-checker.x)*(x-checker.x) + (y-checker.y)*(y-checker.y) < checker.radius*checker.radius){ alert('He clicked'); }`. **Also, you have a typo:** `y -= canvas.offsetTop`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a close look at your conditionals:

```
if(x >= checker.x + 32 && x <= checker.x - 32) {
    if(y >= checker.y + 32 && y <= checker.y -32) {
        alert("HE CLICKED");
    }
}
```

1. You are using `&&` implying that both conditions have to be true at the same time - which isn't possible because you are checking for click *outside the checker's boundaries*.
2. Instead, you should look for the click within the boundaries of the checker.

Like so:

```
if(x <= checker.x + 32 && x >= checker.x - 32) {
    if(y <= checker.y + 32 && y >= checker.y -32) {
        alert("HE CLICKED");
    }
}
```